# Can I get the created time of a PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, ddl, maintenance, metadata

I'm using PostgreSQL-13.0.

Is there a way I can get the created time or last modified time of a database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the time when a database was created. I am not even certain what would be meant by that: if you restore a database from a `pg_dump`, would the restore time be the creation time? What about restoring a file system backup?

The last modified time is easier: get the object ID of the database with

```
SELECT datname, oid FROM pg_database;
```

Then change to the data directory, into the `base` subdirectory, then into the directory that belongs to the database. There, find the file with the most recent modification date. (If you have non-default tablespaces, you'll have to look there as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out when your cluster was initialised (not a single database):

```
SELECT version() AS "Version", 
to_timestamp (system_identifier >> 32) as clusterinit_timestamp
FROM pg_control_system();
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint! But I'm maintaining a env that has too many databases, I need to confirm which dbs should be removed.

Thanks anyway, I may use your method next time I need it!